# JWNL: identifying nouns in the given query

Tags: java

I am doing the work in JWNL.
I want the usery to enter an query and then I need to find the words comprising the query. From those words I need to identify the nouns. Here's is the code I have written:

```
  public class graph
   {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JWNLException 
      {
          WordNetHelper.initialize("F:\\file_properties.xml");
          System.out.println("Enter the query term!!!");
          Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);              
          while(sc.hasNext())
          {
              String s= sc.next();
              String[] result = s.split("\\s");
              for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++) 
                  {
                       System.out.println(result[x]);
                  }                   

           }         

      }
    }
```

How should I proceed further? And if there is any change required in the code, then please specify it.

Answer (score 0):

- You can import [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml). The Part-Of-Speech Tagger (POS Tagger) reads text in some language and assigns parts of speech to each word (and other token), such as noun, verb, adjective, etc
- You can also use [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) which provides an API to an English lexicon with possible parts-of-speech.